# Transposing multiple related columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot, cross-apply

While transposing single columns is pretty straight forward I need to transpose a large amount of data with 3 sets of , 10+  related columns needed to be transposed.

```
create table test
(month int,year int,po1 int,po2 int,ro1 int,ro2 int,mo1 int,mo2 int, mo3 int);

insert into test 
values
(5,2013,100,20,10,1,3,4,5),(4,2014,200,30,20,2,4,5,6),(6,2015,200,80,30,3,5,6,7) ;

select * FROM test;
```

gives

| month | year | po1 | po2 | ro1 | ro2 | mo1 | mo2 | mo3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2013 | 100 | 20 | 10 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 2014 | 200 | 30 | 20 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 2015 | 200 | 80 | 30 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

Transposing using UNPIVOT

```
select
  month, year, 
  PO, RO, MO
from ( SELECT * from test) src

unpivot
    ( PO for Description in (po1, po2))unpiv1
unpivot
    (RO for Description1 in (ro1, ro2)) unpiv2
unpivot
    (MO for Description2 in (mo1, mo2, mo3)) unpiv3

order by year
```

Gives me this

| month | year | PO | RO | MO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2013 | 100 | 10 | 3 |
| 5 | 2013 | 100 | 10 | 4 |
| 5 | 2013 | 100 | 10 | 5 |
| 5 | 2013 | 100 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 2013 | 100 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 2013 | 100 | 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 2013 | 20 | 10 | 3 |
| 5 | 2013 | 20 | 10 | 4 |
| 5 | 2013 | 20 | 10 | 5 |
| 5 | 2013 | 20 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 2013 | 20 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 2013 | 20 | 1 | 5 |
| 4 | 2014 | 200 | 20 | 4 |
| 4 | 2014 | 200 | 20 | 5 |
| 4 | 2014 | 200 | 20 | 6 |
| 4 | 2014 | 200 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 2014 | 200 | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 2014 | 200 | 2 | 6 |
| 4 | 2014 | 30 | 20 | 4 |
| 4 | 2014 | 30 | 20 | 5 |
| 4 | 2014 | 30 | 20 | 6 |
| 4 | 2014 | 30 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 2014 | 30 | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 2014 | 30 | 2 | 6 |
| 6 | 2015 | 200 | 30 | 5 |
| 6 | 2015 | 200 | 30 | 6 |
| 6 | 2015 | 200 | 30 | 7 |
| 6 | 2015 | 200 | 3 | 5 |
| 6 | 2015 | 200 | 3 | 6 |
| 6 | 2015 | 200 | 3 | 7 |
| 6 | 2015 | 80 | 30 | 5 |
| 6 | 2015 | 80 | 30 | 6 |
| 6 | 2015 | 80 | 30 | 7 |
| 6 | 2015 | 80 | 3 | 5 |
| 6 | 2015 | 80 | 3 | 6 |
| 6 | 2015 | 80 | 3 | 7 |

I will like to turn it to something like this. Is that possible?

| month | year | PO | RO | MO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2013 | 100 | 10 | 3 |
| 5 | 2013 | 20 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 2013 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 4 | 2014 | 200 | 20 | 4 |
| 4 | 2014 | 30 | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 2014 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 6 | 2015 | 200 | 30 | 5 |
| 6 | 2015 | 80 | 3 | 6 |
| 6 | 2015 | 0 | 0 | 7 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe use a query like below which creates rows as per your design using CROSS APPLY

```
select month,year,po,ro,mo from 
test cross apply 
(values (po1,ro1,mo1), (po2,ro2,mo2),(0,0,mo3))v(po,ro,mo)
```

see demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dae556cc5639a395c526bed7412a69d2)

Comment: This may be possible, I'll Check and report

Answer (score 2):

`Unpivot` acts similar as `union`,Use `union all` in your case

```
SELECT month,
       year,
       po1 AS PO,
       ro1 AS RO,
       mo1 AS MO
FROM   test
UNION ALL
SELECT month,
       year,
       po2,
       ro2,
       mo2
FROM   test
UNION ALL
SELECT month,
       year,
       0,
       0,
       mo2
FROM   test
```

Comment: thanks, this works but there about 26 columns for one of them @DhruvJoshi solution works better.